# Gestión de conexiones en Flask y MySQL

Tags: python, flask, mysqldb

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto web en Flask y MySQL sin usar ORM para gestionar las conexiones y manipulación de datos (Decidí usarlo así ya que prefiero escribir SQL directamente).

Para la conexión uso lo siguiente que está en un archivo llamado conexion.py:

```
import MySQLdb

def conectar():
    db = MySQLdb.connect(
        host = '127.0.0.1',    
        user = 'root',   
        passwd = 'secret',  
        db = 'myDB'
    )
    return db
```

El proyecto tiene varios módulos implementados bajo Blueprint y lo que hago es que en cada petición solicito una conexión con la base de datos y la instancia resultante
lo paso como parámetro al modelo. Ejemplo:

```
from flask import Blueprint, request, render_template, \
              flash, g, session, redirect, url_for, jsonify

from app.db.models import clientes
from app.db import conexion
mod_cliente = Blueprint('Cliente', __name__, url_prefix='/cliente')


@mod_cliente.route('/')
def index():
    error = None
    cnx = conexion.conectar()
    try:
        # paso el parámetro al def getAll de la clase Cliente del modelo
        datos = clientes.Cliente.getAll(cnx)

        # si tengo más consultas utilizo la misma instancia de conexión,
        # eso para no abrir tantas conexiones en una petición
        ...

        # despues de todo, cierro la conexion
        cnx.close()

    except Exception, e:
        datos = {}
        error = e
    return render_template('clientes_index.html', datos=datos, error=error)
```

Porsión de la clase modelo Cliente:

```
import MySQLdb

class Cliente:

    @classmethod
    def getAll(self, cnx):

        cursor = cnx.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        cursor.execute("select * from clientes")
        datos = cursor.fetchall()
        cursor.close()

        return datos
```

El problema es que cuando existen peticiones concurrentes, se alcanza el máximo de conexiones permitidas establecido en la configuración de MySQL lo que
ocasiona que el servidor se bloquee(por así decirlo).

Me gustaría saber si hay algún método para evitar que se creen tantas instancias por varias peticiones concurrentes.

Comment: Quizás es que no cierras las conexiones? Por otro lado, no nos dices cómo lanzas la aplicación. Si lo haces con el servidor de desarrollo incluido en Flask (`flask run`), entonces no puede ser un problema de concurrencia, pues este servidor tiene un único proceso y un único hilo, atendiendo a los clientes de uno en uno y nunca a la vez. En este caso se trataría seguramente de que cada vez que atiendes a un nuevo cliente abres una conexión nueva, pero nunca la cierras, por lo que el número de conexiones se va agotando.

Comment: Muchas gracias abulafia por tu comentario. La aplicación está lanzada en un servidor apache

Comment: Apache en principio utiliza un modelo pre-fork, es decir, tiene lanzados de antemano varios procesos `httpd` y cada uno de ellos se ocupa de un cliente. Si, por ejemplo, lanzó 6 procesos, podría ocuparse de 6 clientes simultáneos. Si llegan más, son atendidos por turnos cuando uno de esos 6 trabajadores quede libre. No tengo claro si utiliza multi-hilo dentro de cada proceso, pero no creo que lo haga en el caso de ejecutar python, por culpa del GIL. Así que mi comentario anterior sigue siendo pertinente. Debes cerrar las conexiones. Mira [aqui](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/tutorial/dbcon/)

Comment: Muchas gracias abulafia, después de cada uso que le doy a la instancia de conexión lo suelo cerrar, pero ahora que mencionaste sobre la falta de cierre me fije que en el bloque de la except: no se está cerrando, es decir que cada vez que se produce una exception no se está cerrando la conexión. Nuevamente gracias por tu comentario, saludos!

Comment: Interesante lectura la que me recomendaste.

Comment: No es muy eficiente crear conexiones y cerrarlas cada vez que el modelo debe consultar la base de datos. Lo normal es crear una conexión con la bd al inicio de la petición (y usar esa conexión todas las veces que sea necesario durante la construcción de la respuesta), y cerrarla después cuando ya la respuesta está lista para enviar al cliente. Eso es lo que se explica en el enlace que te indiqué, donde usa el objeto global `g` para almacenar la conexión y así no tener que hacerla de nuevo, y el decorador `teardown_appcontext` para marcar la función a ejecutar al terminar (que la cierra)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la traducción. No fue sarcasmo mi comentario, en realidad es muy interesante y leyendo encontré otro enlace que explica el uso del contexto de la aplicación [aquí](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/appcontext/#app-context). Me sirvió de sobre manera tu comentario, saludos!